# center scaling issue with slider in canvas using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js for my canvas.

In this I scaling my image using the slider.

but when I using the below code then it's getting scale properly but when I change the position of the image then I try it again make the image into the center then scale proportionally.

`image.scale(sizePercent).center().setCoords();`

I tried many but not getting proper solution, I need that, when I scale image it should be proportionally where it is.

I also tried to pass current x and y of the image in the canvas

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use these options for your image instead of `.center()`:

```
{
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
}
```

I've prepared an example of my suggestion above for you here

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-morse-yfn7q?file=/src/index.js